Does World of Goo 2 have any kind of co-op multiplayer on PC?
The Linux version of World of Goo had same-screen co-op for playing with multiple mice. Does World of Goo 2 for PC have any kind of co-op capabilities?

From what I gather, local co-op is exclusive to the Nintendo Switch version.  A Nintendo webpage states:

And if you’d like to goo with two (or four, or even eight!), local cooperative play* is exclusive to the Nintendo Switch™ game. Build together!

This aligns with the Game Wiki:

The Switch version of the game will have local co-op multiplayer mode up to 4 players, it is unknown whenever local co-op will appear in the PC versions in any capacity.

The PC version does not appear to have any co-op support - be it locally or online (The Switch version also doesn't appear to have online support).  Watching videos of the game depicts a very basic game menu that doesn't seem to indicate any kind of online aspect to it.
